Creality K1 Max Filament Won't Feed
I'm unable to feed the filament past the highlighted figure in my Creality K1 Max. There was no problem with filling it before the filament ran out on a print overnight. Any hints as to what might be wrong?


When filament has to pass several tubes and/or tube connectors it is always recommend to cut your filament under an angle. A sharp pointed piece of filament is less likely to get stuck behind ledges/ridges, personally I make sharp filament starts with an angle of about 30°, below an example of cutting filament under 45°.
This is also common practice for certain extruders/hotends, in this case it appears to be the filament run-out sensor. Note that straightening the filament (bend the first 10 - 20 cm against the curvature of the filament spool winding) will also help. When the filament isn't straightened it is more likely to catch on ledges or ridges.
If you don't care to cut the filament under an angle or straighten the filament, or if the above doesn't work, another proven solution that sometimes helps (I use is for feeding some of my extruders) is rotating the filament; you rotate it away from the position that is preventing it to progress further.

Source: AnkerMake

The blue arrow appears to be pointing at a filament run out detector. In many cases these are physical switches which come in contact with the filament. Inspecting the internal image of a random filament run out detector ...

... we can see the filament exiting one guide tube and entering another.  If the tip of the filament is bent, it will likely not be able to travel through the filament run out detector.
Try cutting off the bent tip of the filament.  Or straightening it through other means.
